# Edge slide modals (E)ven: On/off, Alt or (C)lamp: On/off - conflicts in keymap

Tags: keymap

I have customised my transform modal map (with E to scale, Alt for Precision mode and C for Clear constraints) and now my Vertex/ Edge slide modals cannot be used to toggle Even and Clamping.
[image]

What do I need to edit to make this work again?
In the default keymap there does not seem to be a particular modal for the slide operator, since it uses the Transform modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I see that the industry compatible keymap doesn't use the Alt or E key in the modal keymap, nor does Blender's default one, that's why it won't work. These modals are hardcoded, see https://developer.blender.org/T37427.